# NoReverseMatch at /customer/1/list/

Tags: django, upload

I am trying to make a upload function in the form, but when I click upload button, it throws error: NoReverseMatch at /customer/1/list/

Here is code in the view

```
def list(request,pk):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            form.cId = pk;
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
            # render(request, 'list.html', {'documents': documents, 'form': form})
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return
```

Here is code in the url

```
url(r'^customer/(?P<pk>\d+)/list/$', Views.list, name='list'),
```

please help

Comment: What is url you are uploading to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))` with `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list', args=[pk]))`. Please check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) to see how to use reverse. Hope it helps!!

Comment: It is still failing. the form is 

 <form action="{% url 'list' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Do I miss anything here?

Comment: ` <form action="{% url 'list' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` will not work, because it expects an argument. So please pass a argument like ` <form action="{% url 'list' 'your_argument' %}" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">` where `your_argument` is equivalent to **pk**. And this info should be passed as context from view to template, else it will not work.